# Django app -> Elastic Beanstalk instance deployment instance - Site hanging

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) tutorial to deploy a Django app on AWS EB instance, and got to the **eb deploy** stage.

My log files seem to imply that everything is ok, except the health checker raises some issues:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.2.9 - - [28/Mar/2024:17:00:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.34.136 - - [28/Mar/2024:17:01:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.2.9 - - [28/Mar/2024:17:01:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

However, I go to the site URL it just hangs and then stops. Could this be because the allowed host url is http and not https, which is not working with Firefox?

The loading page issues state:

> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

I am quite new to web app development, so some pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Happy to provide more info on request.